# Not all of my constructors are being imported?

Tags: c++, linker

I'm making a heap class to be importable with `heap.h` and my constructors including bool types do not work, yet every other constructor and function imported works.

Here is what's in `heap.h`:

```
#ifndef __HEAP_INCLUDED__
#define __HEAP_INCLUDED__

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class heap{
int capacity;
bool isMinHeap;  //1 is min heap -- ascending order
vector<int> * content;
public:
heap();
heap(bool t);
heap(vector<int> * input);
heap(vector<int> * input, bool t);

void print();
void prettyPrint();
int parent(int i);
int leftChild(int i);
int rightChild(int i);
int size();
int getMax();
void insert(int data);
void heapifyDown(int index);
void heapifyUp(int index);
int invalidChild(int index);
int deleteMax();
int deleteMin();
bool minDir();
int at(int index);
};

vector<int> * heapSort(vector<int> * input);

void swap(vector<int> * vec, int a, int b);

#endif
```

Here are the defined constructors in `heap.cpp`. Note, all constructors work fine when I add a main to this file to test stuff:

```
class heap{
    vector<int> * content;
    int capacity = 256;
    bool isMinHeap;  //1 is min heap -- ascending order
        
    public:
    heap(){
        content = new vector<int>;
        isMinHeap = 0;
    }
    heap(bool t){
        content = new vector<int>;
        isMinHeap = t;
    }
    heap(vector<int> * input){
        content = input;
        isMinHeap = true;
        for(int i = content->size()/2; i >= 0; i--){
            heapifyDown(i);
        }
    }
    heap(vector<int> * input, bool t){
        content = input;
        isMinHeap = t;
        for(int i = content->size()/2; i >= 0; i--){
            heapifyDown(i);
        }
    }
//other functions below
}
```

The constructors with bool do not work in `main.cpp`, which has `#include "heap.h"` at the top. The files are all in the same directory and I am compiling with this command: `g++ heap.cpp main.cpp -o main`. Why do two of my constructors not work?

The error I see is

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccwomODk.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x4e2): undefined reference to `heap::heap(bool)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

`-Wall` does not elaborate on the issue. I'm pretty sure the issue is with my linking somewhere because the constructors work inside of `heap.cpp` when I use them in there.

Comment: Unrelated (probably): [Phear the double underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)!!!!!!

Comment: Your `heap.h` declares a class heap, and your `heap.cpp` declares another one (this one with more definitions). Put declarations in the header, and only definiitions in the implementation file. (e.g. in `heap.cpp` have `#include "heap.h" heap::heap(bool t) { ... }`.

Comment: Your cpp file looks wierd...

Comment: This is not how you define members of a class out-of-line. You are giving two different definitions of the class `heap` resulting in an ODR violation and undefined behavior.

Comment: Unrelated (probably): [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Did you first try to write a simple class declaration, and simple class definition?  If you did that, you should have never wound up with an entire block of code (the heap.cpp) looking like that.  `class foo { public: void someFunction(); };` would be in a header, and in the cpp file: `#include <foo.h> #include <iostream> void foo::someFunction() { std::cout << "stuff"; }`.  The mistake you made is a tell-tale sign you either did not follow the C++ book you're using, or you guessed what a class implementation looked like, and wrote all of this, with the final results ending up all wrong.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but names that contain two consecutive underscores (`__HEAP_INCLUDED__`) are reserved for use by the implementation. Don’t use them in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing with the class in the `.cpp` file is wrong. You are not allowed to define the class twice. There must only be one `class heap { /*...*/ };` in the program (but it may be included in multiple `.cpp` files). Otherwise the one-definition-rule (ODR) is violated and the program has undefined behavior.

So remove everything you are showing from `heap.cpp`.

To define the constructors of `heap` in the `heap.cpp` file, you need to use this syntax:

```
#include "heap.h"

heap::heap() {
    /*...*/
}

heap::heap(bool t) {
    /*...*/
}

//...
```

and so on. The other member functions must be defined in a similar way, e.g.:

```
void heap::print() {
    /*...*/
}
```

---

Furthermore, if you want to have a default member initializer as in

```
int capacity = 256;
```

add it in the declaration in the `.h` file instead.

---

I also want to add that having a pointer-to-`std::vector` as member is almost surely a wrong approach as well, but out-of-scope for the question.

Comment: What's wrong with using std::vector? I make frequent use of size() and pushback(). Access and modification is a little annoying but it works

Comment: @HarrisB The vector itself is not the problem. That it is `vector<int> * content;` instead of `vector<int> content;` is suspicious. What makes you use a pointer here?

Answer (score 0):

> When you declare a program element such as a class, function, or
> variable, its name can only be "seen" and used in certain parts of
> your program. The context in which a name is visible is called its
> scope. For example, if you declare a variable x within a function, x
> is only visible within that function body.

It seems you broke ODR rule so bad. Your class members including constructors has no body declared in the source file(heap.cpp).
Use '::' to make class members have a body:

```
//heap.cpp
"heap.h"
heap::heap()
{
}
heap:heap(vector<int> * input, bool t)
{
}
int heap::parent(int i)
{
    return i;
}
// this is how you create a body for function that are class members
// the same should be done for all other functions
```